# What action is it to combine two shang gou into "a single one-handed weapon"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, actions

The shang gou weapon entry reads:

> Forged in pairs, these solid metal blades end in curved hooks, while the hand guards are hammered into outward-facing spiked crescents.
>
> **Benefit**: Both the crescent and the tip of the hilt are sharpened for combat. They can be wielded as single weapons or with two-weapon fighting styles. The weapons gain the disarm special weapon feature when used individually. A pair of shang gou can also be formed into a single one-handed weapon to gain the trip special feature.

What is the action (if any?) to combine a pair of shang gou into one one-handed weapon as mentioned in this entry? I couldn't find any answers on the Paizo forums or on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It is unclear, but I would say its a Free Action

There is no information about what action is used to "combine" a weapon, and the [Shang Gou](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/shang-gou/) (aka the Chinese *[Hook Sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_sword)*) seems to be the only weapon in the game that has such ruling. Similar weapons, like the [Sansetusukon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/sansetsukon-three-section-staff) (Three-section staff), have their "alternative" fighting mode baked into the standard stats of the weapon ("blocking, disarm").

That said, you can pretty much assume its a *Free Action*, because the weapon's entry on the table simply says "trip or disarm (see text)", that would mean that this behavior is simply part of how the weapon works, nothing else. It's similar to changing your grip on a *Bastard Sword*.